# Python Error - TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'NoneType'

Tags: python, numpy, typeerror

I have the next for loop inside a function

```
def Cost_F(Y, Ypred, m):

    for i in range(0,m):
        # Y and Ypred
        X = np.matmul(-Y, np.log10(Ypred))
```

Dimensions for Y and Ypred are both **(10,1)**.

Type of Y and Ypred => **class 'numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix'**

Error from cmd => **TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'NoneType'**

Comment: im using **print(type(Y))** and **print(type(Ypred))**  and i got this output from cmd **class 'numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix'**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
-Y
```

does not work as you are trying to use it. What you mean is:

```
-1*Y
```

What python is trying to do in your case is:

```
None - Y
```

which will obviously not work. That is, beacuse it interprets `-` to be an operand with a left and a right side. In your case you provide no left side, so it assumes `None` and then can't find any implementation for the `-` where the left is `None` and the right is a matrix

Comment: This answer is only correct if `Y` is an object that does not have the unary operator `__neg__()` implemented. 

This is obviously untrue for objects that do have it implement (e.g., `Y=np.array([1,2,3]); print(-Y)`

Comment: Your answer is misleading and implies the solution is `-1*Y`. Your statement "In your case you provide no left side, so it assumes None and then can't find any implementation for the - where the left is None and the right is a matrix" is untrue in this case. Rather the OP has passed in `Y` that cannot be negated (not an object that implements `__neg__()`) or , in the case of numpy, `Y` is indeed a matrix but contains NoneType (e.g., `-np.matrix([None])` will produce the same error).